# creating new project with firebreath

Tags: npapi, firebreath

I am currently tasked to create an NPAPI plugin. And I've read that it will be better to do it with firebreath. The problem is I don't know how to start a project. So I researched and found a tutorial from firebreath.org. But when I tried what he had done in the tutorial, I can't do it. He used CMD to retrieve the source code for firebreath. The command was "git clone git://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath firebreath"... In the tutorial it retrieved the source code.. in my case it returned an error... saying git is not a recognized batch command... any ideas what happened? thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install git. If you need help with that, it's probably a question for superuser.com, since it's not really a programming question.

Comment: Not only does git need to be installed, but it needs to be in your path to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can either install Git from [here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) or simply download the firebreath zip file. Once you've done that, follow the instructions as in this answer: [How is an ActiveX wrapper created with FireBreath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903631/how-is-an-activex-wrapper-created-with-firebreath)

As Taxilian says, git has to be in your system path (environment variables of Windows) if you want to use git from the commandline. Setting/adding the path happens during the installation of git.

Answer (score 0):

If 'git' is not recognized in windows even after adding to the system path try using [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) which provides 'Git Bash' (a command prompt like interface) which is convenient for using git by commands.